# Defining a variable vs. initializing

Tags: c, arrays, variables, c-preprocessor

So, I am led to believe by my professor that when declaring the size of an array, it is best to use `#define` vs. just declaring it as a normal integer. Is this correct?

If so, why?

Also, if this is correct, what am I doing wrong? When I try to  do this I get an message:

> error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant

every time I call the array. The code works if I just initialize it as an integer.

The definition and usage can be seen in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define handsize 5
#define size 52

// Create function prototypes
void create_deck (int deck[]);
void shuffle_deck (int size, int deck[]);
void display_card (int card);
void display_hand (int size, int hand[]);
int popCard (int *size, int deck[]);
int findScore (int size, int hand[]);

int main()
{
    // declare/ initialize variables
    int c, d, p, win = 0, lose = 0 , tie = 0, /*handsize = 0, size = 52,*/ deck[size], hand[handsize], dealer[handsize];
    char play;
    srand(time(NULL));      // attach random number generator to time function for truly random variables

    // explain program to user and ask if they want to play
    printf("This program is a card game that adds the values of all the\n");
    printf("cards in the players hand, and the computers hand. The highest hand wins.\n");
    printf("Would you like to play? Please press 'y' for yes, any other key for no.\n");
    scanf("%c", &play);     // if the user wants to play, continue the program

    // while loop that continues as long as the user wants to play
    while (play == 'y'){

        // call functions to create and shuffle the deck
        create_deck(deck);
        shuffle_deck (size, deck);

        // for loop that calls the popCard function to deal the top card in the deck
        for (c = 0; c < 5; c++){
            hand[c] = popCard (&size, deck);        // player gets a card
            dealer[c] = popCard (&size, deck);      // computer gets a card
            handsize++;
            // call the display_hand function to display the individual cards in the players hand
            printf("\nYour hand consists of:\n");
            display_hand (handsize, hand);
            // call the display_hand function to display the individual cards in the dealers hand
            printf("Dealer hand consists of:\n");
            display_hand (handsize, dealer);
        }

        // call the findScore function for both the user and the computer
        p = findScore (handsize, hand);
        d = findScore (handsize, dealer);

        // show the value of the user and computers hands
        printf("\nThe value of your hand is %i\n", p);
        printf("\nThe value of the dealers hand is %i\n", d);

        // if statements that keep track of wins, losses and ties
        if (p > d)
            win++;
        if (p == d)
            tie++;
        if (p < d)
            lose++;

        // show number of times player has won, lost, tied.  Then ask to play again
        printf("You have won %i times, tied %i times, and lost %i times\n", win, tie, lose);
        printf("\nWould you like to play again?\n");
        fflush(stdin);      // flush the input buffer to stop false readings
        scanf("%c", &play); // read the user input to determine if they want to play again
    }
    printf("Goodbye");
    return 0;
```

**I hope this is what you wanted

Comment: The idea behind using `#define` is that the actual number only shows up in one place. That way, when you need to change it, you can just change it in that one place and not worry about forgetting to change it somewhere else. Why you're getting an error, I don't know because you haven't shown us your code.

Comment: Jason, I've added your definition to the question, now we just need your use of it. Once you tell us that, I'll update the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbolic constants (either `#define` or actual constants) are generally preferred.

What happens, for example, when your code is peppered with the value `1440` but you use that number for both twips per inch and kilobytes per floppy (very much showing my age here)?

Then all of a sudden your floppies become 2.88M. You then have to go through *all* your code looking for `1440` and figuring out if it meant the twips or kilobytes version, and changing the relevant ones. So not only do you have to make the change in multiple places (bad enough), you may also have to figure out whether the change you be made at *each* place.

Had you instead done:

```
#define TWIPS_PER_INCH 1440
#define KB_PER_FLOPPY  1440
```

and then peppered your code with the symbolic names, you could have then just changed *one* line, without too much thinking or analysis required.

---

There's a school of thought that any number other than zero or one (and possibly negative one) should have a symbolic constant of some sort. Just make sure you don't make the mistake of doing:

```
#define FOURTEEN_HUNDRED_AND_FORTY 1440
```

like one of my minions once tried. I had endless fun trying to explain why *that* was a bad idea :-)

---

As to your error, it's certainly possible to declare an array with a preprocessor constant as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define VAR 42
int main (void) {
    char xyzzy[VAR];
    strcpy (xyzzy, "pax is awesome");
    puts (xyzzy);
    return 0;
}
```

However, consider the following lines in your code:

```
#define size 52
void shuffle_deck (int size, int deck[]);
void display_hand (int size, int hand[]);
int popCard (int *size, int deck[]);
int findScore (int size, int hand[]);
hand[c] = popCard (&size, deck);
// and possibly many others.
```

Because preprocessing is a textual substitution done early in the compilation process, those lines following the first are going to become:

```
void shuffle_deck (int 52, int deck[]);
void display_hand (int 52, int hand[]);
int popCard (int *52, int deck[]);
int findScore (int 52, int hand[]);
hand[c] = popCard (&52, deck);
```

and they will cause all sorts of problems, among them that `52` is not a valid variable name in a function prototype, and that you cannot take the address of an integer literal in C because it *has* no address.

In order to fix this, you define the *initial* size as a constant:

```
#define INIT_SZ 52
```

and use that to set the initial value of a *variable* `size` which you can later change, something like:

```
void doSomethingThatChangesSize (int *pSize) {
    (*pSize) += 42;
}

int size = INIT_SZ; // this is the only way you use INIT_SZ
:
doSomethingThatChanges (&size);
```

Comment: I i defined the variable as this:  #define size 52 Is this incorrect?

Comment: @Jason, no, that's correct, provided you haven't done something silly like put a `;` at the end. You need to post that comment _and_ the use of `size` into your question (or put it here and I'll paste it for you).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for not including my code the first time around. I guess I didn't realize it was such an involved question.

Comment: No probs, @Jason, it's usually best to include the code (or a small, relevant portion of it) since that generally makes the problem obvious, and we don't have to attempt what Raymond Chan calls "psychic debugging" :-) In this case it was using the preprocessor symbol in ways that made the compiler barf.